# Performing calculation where there are common column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select values, perform some calculations, let's say multiply two columns,  and then add them where one of the column value is the same. For example, if I have a table like the following:

```
id     prm
1      12
3      14
1      13
2      20
1      17
3      11
```

I want to first multiply id and prm, then add them wherever there is common id's, so 1st, 3rd, and 5th rows would be added, and 2nd and 6th rows would be added. Then I want the output to be in descending order of id. The final out put would look like:

```
75 40 42
```

Because 3*14+3*11=75, 2*20=40, and 1*12+1*13+1*17=42.
I hope my question is clear. 
Is there a way to do this in one sql statement?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07290/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, sum(id*prm)
from tablename
group by id order by 2 desc
```

Check this-> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07290/8 if this matches your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can just `group by` id.

```
select id, sum(id*prm)
from yourtable
group by id
```

To get the result in a single row, you could do

```
select 
max(case when id = 1 then `total` end) as id1,
max(case when id = 2 then `total` end) as id2,
max(case when id = 3 then `total` end) as id3
from (
select id, sum(id*prm) as `total`
from yourtable
group by id) t
```